# Using TypeScript with Express and static files

Tags: node.js, express, sass

I've created a simple Express application and I compile it to TypeScript using TypeScript compiler, then I run the JS compiled script. The problem is, when I tried to implement `node-sass-middleware`:

```js
  app.use(
    sass({
      src: join(__dirname, "..", "src", "style"),
      dest: join(__dirname, "style"),
      debug: true,
    })
  );
```

1. `__dirname` is equal to dist folder.
2. Styles files aren't compiling, and the debug output is:

```
[sass]  skip: / nothing to do
[sass]  skip: /common/index.js nothing to do
```

App folder structure is:

```
src
  - common
      index.ts
  - style
      index.scss
  app.ts
  index.ts
  server.ts

dist
  - common
      index.js
  app.js
  index.ts
  server.ts
```

Can someone explain how to properly use TypeScript with Express.js with TypeScript to static compilation and Sass usage? Pretty please.